# Is there a way for me to get specific words from an output of a command in bash?

Tags: bash

For example, when running the dpkg command,

```
dpkg -s autofs
```

I would get an output like

`dpkg-query: package 'autofs' is not installed and no information is available`

But I just want to get the

`not installed`

part so that I can further use it for my script. Is there a command that can help me with it?

Comment: Piping to `grep` with the `-o` option is useful for this. Also, since that error probably goes to stderr, you'll need to redirect stderr to stdout when piping: `command1 2>&1 | command2`

Comment: It most likely returns an error code, you can check the status instead of looking for a specific string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the words `not installed` are locale specific, so it will fail with anything but English locales. It is also non-predictable because it is not a published API Application Programming Interface.

So, even with some precautions, do not use this:

```sh
LC_MESSAGES=C dpkg-query --status autofs 2>&1 | grep -o 'not installed'
```

Check the return status of the `dpkg-query` command instead:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

package='autofs'

if dpkg-query --status "$package" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  printf 'Package %s is installed!\n' "$package"
else
  printf 'Package %s is not installed!\n' "$package"
fi
```